# Using a variable as a key name inside a filter function

Tags: javascript, filter, scope

Trying to figure out how to use a variable as a key name inside a filter function.

**Example array of objects:**

```
const data = [{"itemID": 11, "Complete": true, "Started": true},{"itemID": 16, "Complete": false, "Started": false}];
```

**Conditional statement:**

```
if(isStartMode){
    const currentMode = 'Started'
  } else {
    const currentMode = 'Complete'
  }
```

**Variable**

```
var possible_ItemID = 16;
```

**Filter function**

```
const lineItem = data.filter((item) => item.itemID === possible_ItemID && item.{currentMode} !== true)

console.log(lineItem)
```

I'm looking for a way to switch either "Started" or "Complete" where it says {currentMode}, without having to make separate hardcoded statements for each: item.Started or item.Complete

There's just something I'm missing in the syntax...

Comment: `const currentMode = isStartMode ? 'Started' : 'Complete';` would be the proper way to set the value

Comment: Bracket notation. `item[currentMode]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I should have just done it like this - use [], and declare the variable outside of the if statement.

```
var currentMode;
if(isStartMode){
    currentMode = 'Started'
  } else {
    currentMode = 'Complete'
  }

const lineItem = data.filter((item) => item.itemID === possible_ItemID && item[currentMode] !== true)
```